# Deploy Twig Standalone project to Live Server

Tags: php, html, templates, deployment, twig

I decided to use Twig as a standalone template motor to make a static web site, with the idea to grow it further into a database dynamic MVC project. By the moment I just have a static website.

I am working offline, using a local php server, I haven't had troubles working and updating the project in my browser locally. The thing is, when I upload the project to the server, nothing works, I get a 500 error.

I want to know how can I deploy my website to the live server, and what is the best approach to make it work without uploading all the bunch of vendors files and just keep functional ones. I use to work with smarty and was very easy to deploy, but I think twig must be equally easy.

**This is my file tree:**

[image: my file tree]

Comment: Did you check your errors logs?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing additional apart of the error 500. =(